# SAPUI5 Browser Caching?

Tags: caching, sapui5, offline

I have been working on offline application of sapui5. I have gone through these two links.

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-45756

http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/91/f080966f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm

But I am still unable to implement cache handling in my application.

**My requirement**

1. Even if network is not there the application should load from browser cache.
2. view , controller and sapui5 library should be cache.

Comment: What is the problem? It's the first document that is relevant for you. Read up on HTML5 App Cache. If you're not familiar with the app cache, start with a more simple project than SAPUI5.

Comment: You've not stated the actual programming problem you've come up with, nor the solutions you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cache control feature in sapui5 which will store files in caches in browser. You have to include cache control in neo app.json file